# JQuery stops my navbar to dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I've got a .jsp file, which uses this script

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

in my body, I include a menu.html into my .jsp file like this:

```
<body>
    <jsp:include page="menu.html"/>
</body>
```

The problem is, that my menu isn't working anymore when I include the javascript. By "not working" I mean, that the dropdown-menu doesn't work anymore. Why is that so?

home.jsp

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:include page="menu.html"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

menu.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">WORKS<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/link1">DOES NOT WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link2">DOES NOT WORK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: what is the css you are using?

Comment: I'm using the script to use this here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panel-table-with-filters-per-column
 You can find the css file there. Edit: also I'm using bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap-theme.min.css, bootstrap-theme.css and bootstrap.css

Comment: also you can add the js file at the end of your body instead of in the head tag

Comment: what is the js that you are using? cause the base bootstrap and the css from that other page isnt making this work, i dont think its the js file

Comment: I've included the .js and .css from bootsnipp.com to use the table and in my .jsp file I also include the _jquery-1.10.2.min.js_ and _bootstrap.min.js_
You can find the full code here: http://textuploader.com/dry2i and http://textuploader.com/dry28

Comment: check my fiddle below and see if you have it set up the way i have it

Comment: did you try taking it out of the head sections and adding the .js files to the bottom of the page?

Comment: The jquery.min.js comes before the bootstrap.js files and I have it included in my project.
Yes, I've also tried to add the script files at the bottom of the page (right before and also right after the body), only the filter button works, but not the dropdown. When I delete the jquery.min.js, then the dropdown works, but not the filter button.

Comment: Maybe try moving the bootstrap.is to the menu page?

Comment: I've included the bootstrap.js twice (once on the .jsp file and also in my head.html), which I didn't see. I guess the second bootstrap.js somehow blocked the navbar from working. I've removed the entry and now it's working :)

Comment: Thanks, glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing, but this seems to work. Maybe its because you're missing the bootstrap.min.js file? If you aren't, then make sure that the jquery.min.js file comes before all the bootstrap .js files.

https://jsfiddle.net/64hbcvh9/1/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">WORKS<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/Wettkampf/svc/veranstaltung/edit">DOES NOT WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Wettkampf/svc/veranstaltung/findAll">DOES NOT WORK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: your jsfiddle doesn't show the links or any text, only the navbar, but nothing inside of it :/

Comment: You have to view it at 100%